# Access token validation error MS Graph using UserCredentials

Tags: .net, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I am trying to access MS Graph using an AAD account, this account is global admin and has every right delegated. I want to do it without interactive sign-in, i.e using `UserPasswordCredential`. When trying to access MS Graph I get the error:

[image]

My flow:

Getting token:

```
public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            UserPasswordCredential userPasswordCredential = new UserPasswordCredential("user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", "password");
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com");
            AuthenticationResult token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", appId, userPasswordCredential);

            return token.AccessToken;
        }
```

using token:

```
public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
        {
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        Adal adal = new Adal();
                        string accessToken = await adal.GetUserAccessTokenAsync();

                        // Append the access token to the request.
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
                    }));
            return graphClient;
        }
```

Trying to call MS Graph to read events:

```
 try
        {
            // Get events.
            items = await eventsService.GetMyEvents(graphClient);
        }
        catch (ServiceException se)
        {
            //this is where I get the error
        }
```

Delegated Permissions:
[image]

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your resource URI is wrong at least. It should be:

```
public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
{
   UserPasswordCredential userPasswordCredential = new UserPasswordCredential("user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", "password");
   AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com");
   AuthenticationResult token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", appId, userPasswordCredential);

   return token.AccessToken;
}
```

`https://graph.windows.net/` is for Azure AD Graph, not MS Graph.

For MS Graph API you must use `https://graph.microsoft.com/`.

Comment: lord... Sometimes I surprise even my self. Thanks for this, would never have spotted it.

Comment: I typo'd the resource URI in the code example, now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research I understand that we need to obtain Admin permissions. Found in the docs: "App-only scopes (also known as app roles) grant the app the full set of privileges offered by the scope. App-only scopes are typically used by apps that run as a service without a signed-in user being present" 
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes 
I was getting a successful result with the user token since that was under delegated permissions. 
Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After further research it looks like we do need Admin permissions given that we are using the App-only scopes instead of delegated 
permissions. Basic read operations under app-only scope are designated Admin-only. Hopefully this helps someone having the same issue.
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes